# Unmarshal an array nested inside an JSON object

Tags: go

I am having some problems `unmarshalling` this JSON data to a Go slice of items that holds item structs:

```
response := {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "a",
          "products": [
            {
              "name": "c"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "b",
          "products": [
            {
              "name": "d"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "c",
          "products": [
            {
              "name": "e"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

These are my structs:

```
   type Item struct {
     Name string
     Products
    }

    type Products struct {
     Name string
    }
```

The slice should basically be the value the "data" attribute (which is an array) transformed to a Go Items slice. I tried the following, but I kept getting an empty array

```
var items []Item{}
json.Unmarshal(response, &items)
fmt.Println(items)
```

Comment: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: If you had down voted, that is not what I am asking about. That converter only provides you with the model, not the actual slice with the data inside.

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea what you are trying to explain. If you want to unmarshal JSON you need an appropriate struct and json-to-go provides you one. If you want to transform the data: Just do it.

Comment: The model in the question is not compatible with the data. Use json-to-go to get a compatible model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to unmarshal that JSON into a slice, but the root of that JSON is an object (you can tell because the JSON begins with a `{`, indicating the start of an object). You need to account for that outer layer:

```
type Payload struct {
    Data []Item
}

var payload Payload
json.Unmarshal(response, &payload)
fmt.Println(payload.Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this cool tool to help you design your struct
https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/
Also as Adrian said you're trying to unmarshaling json with an array to an object.

```
type Product struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Response struct {
    Data []struct {
        Name     string `json:"name"`
        Products []Product `json:"products"`
    } `json:"data"`
}
```